# What does "cp: omitting directory" mean?

Tags: directory, cp, coreutils

I've issued the following command:

```
sudo cp ~/Transfers/ZendFramework-1.11.4-minimal/library/Zend/* ~/public_html/cmsk.dev/library/
```

When I do this, I start getting the following messages:

```
cp: omitting directory `Tag' 
cp: omitting directory `Test' 
cp: omitting directory `Text' 
cp: omitting directory `TimeSync' 
cp: omitting directory `Tool' 
cp: omitting directory `Translate' 
cp: omitting directory `Uri' 
cp: omitting directory `Validate'
```

and so on...

Why do I get these messages ?

Answer (score 629, accepted):

By default, `cp` copies only the direct files in, and not subdirectories in the directory. The message `cp: omitting directory 'directory'` warns you that the mentioned directory is not copied.

To do so, specify the `-r` (or `--recursive`) option:

```
sudo cp -r ~/Transfers/ZendFramework-1.11.4-minimal/library/Zend/* ~/public_html/cmsk.dev/library/
```

The [manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man1/cp.1.html) (command: `man cp`) contains an overview of the available options.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought that * will deal with it recursively somehow. But no. :D Thanks again. :)

Comment: @MEM: the `*` is expanded by Bash, not by `cp`. Test it yourself by putting `echo ` in front of your command. When expanded, it matches everything with a preceding `...library/Zend/` (the files and directories in it).

Comment: Good news is that `omitting directory 'directory'` doesn't mean that it is deleting that directory.

Comment: @Lekensteyn i was  trying to copy contents of one user to another .so i gained permission  from user with `chmod a+rx ~/` after i tried to copy with `cp /home/2110/*  /home/2111/` it produces error which states permission denied . where i was wrong . sorry to comment because i cant ask duplicate questions. i hope for quick reply :)

Comment: @jasinthpremkumar Files in `/home/2110` are owned by user 2110 while files in `/home/2111` are supposed to be owned by 2111. To set the owner, use something like `sudo chown -R 2111 /home/2111`.

Comment: Note: cp accepts either `-r` or `-R` - I usually use `-R` for recursive because there are some commands that only accept `-R` for recursive.

Answer (score 43):

The message means that `cp` hasn't copied the directories listed. This is the default behaviour for `cp` - only files are copied normally, regardless of if you are specifying them explicitely or using `*`. If you want directories copying use the `-r` switch which means "recursive".

Answer (score 16):

Couple of things here which need to check:

1. Don't use `sudo`. You don't need it, you already have the permissions to write stuff in your own home directory.
2. You can easily view hidden files and directories in the graphical file manager by selecting View/Show Hidden Files from the menu. Or by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>H</kbd>.
3. You need to use the `-R` option in the `cp` command to copy a directory and it's contents.
4. /home isn't your home directory. /home/username is. So you are probably trying to copy from wrong place.
5. The shell is case sensitive, so ~/downloads and ~/Downloads are two different things.

Answer (score 2):

When you are copying a directory like:

```
cp dir1 copy_of_dir1
```

You're only and exactly copying the `dir1` itself and not the files within it, so at the end you will end up with a new directory structure while the structure does not exist.

In other words after it has been copied it will say that my contents is `file1`, `file2`, etc; However these files has not been copied and thus does not exist in it.

So to fix this issue that may came up `cp` by default does not copy the directories and skips them unless you specify `-r` option which copies all the files recursively too.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it says `omitting directory` is because `cp` and all copy utilities, that I know of, create a list of files and sub-directories to be copied before starting to copy the files. When the `--recursive` options is missing, sub-directories get bumped off this list. As such, omitting refers to removal from the copy list, not from your source media. I believe this addresses the meaning of the message.

Answer (score 0):

The **cp** command is used to copy files and directory, not the nested directories,
if you want to copy nesting directories then you can add **-r** after that, where -r means recursive.

**Syntax that you can follow (running as root):**

```
cp -r /source/dir/* /destination/
```

or

```
cp --recursive /source/dir/* /destination/
```

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you have two directories 'Tag' & 'Test'

If you want to copy 'Tag' directory to 'Test' directory use command

```
$ : cp -r Tag Test (case sensitive)
```

Mostly Problem will be solved with above code if not and you get below message like

```
cp: omitting directory `Tag' 
cp: omitting directory `Test'
```

then add some files in 'Tag' directory and then copy those to 'Test' . Actually i to have same problem but solved like what i said secondly.